# I cannot find the sign in option in Power Bi Report Builder

Tags: powerbi, report, publish, powerbi-paginated-reports

Report Builder downloaded for creating paginated reports. but i am unable to publish the report and not able to sign-in in the report builder. I am using pro account

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was an old version. try downloading from the Microsoft Power BI Service.

[image]